# How can I add rows for all dates between two columns?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, resampling, melt

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = [{'ID' : '10', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '15/10/2016'},
          {'ID' : '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016'}]

mydata2 = [{'ID': '10', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '15/10/2016', 'Date': '10/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '10', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '15/10/2016', 'Date': '11/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '10', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '15/10/2016', 'Date': '12/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '10', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '15/10/2016', 'Date': '13/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '10', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '15/10/2016', 'Date': '14/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '10', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '15/10/2016', 'Date': '15/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '10/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '11/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '12/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '13/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '14/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '15/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '16/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '17/10/2016'},
           {'ID': '20', 'Entry Date': '10/10/2016', 'Exit Date': '18/10/2016', 'Date': '18/10/2016'},]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(mydata2)
```

I can't find an answer on how to change 'df' into 'df2'. Maybe I'm not phrasing it right.

I want to take all dates between the dates in two columns 'Entry Date', 'Exit Date', and make a row for each, entering a corresponding date for each row in a new column, 'Date'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshaping, [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and remove column `variable`:

```
#convert columns to datetime
df['Entry Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Entry Date'])
df['Exit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Exit Date'])

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_name='Date')
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df2.drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df2)
            ID
Date          
2016-10-10  10
2016-10-10  20
2016-10-15  10
2016-10-18  20
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) and [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) missing values:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('ID').resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df3)
         Date  ID
0  2016-10-10  10
1  2016-10-11  10
2  2016-10-12  10
3  2016-10-13  10
4  2016-10-14  10
5  2016-10-15  10
6  2016-10-10  20
7  2016-10-11  20
8  2016-10-12  20
9  2016-10-13  20
10 2016-10-14  20
11 2016-10-15  20
12 2016-10-16  20
13 2016-10-17  20
14 2016-10-18  20
```

Last [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) original `DataFrame`:

```
print (pd.merge(df, df3))
   Entry Date  Exit Date  ID       Date
0  2016-10-10 2016-10-15  10 2016-10-10
1  2016-10-10 2016-10-15  10 2016-10-11
2  2016-10-10 2016-10-15  10 2016-10-12
3  2016-10-10 2016-10-15  10 2016-10-13
4  2016-10-10 2016-10-15  10 2016-10-14
5  2016-10-10 2016-10-15  10 2016-10-15
6  2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-10
7  2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-11
8  2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-12
9  2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-13
10 2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-14
11 2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-15
12 2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-16
13 2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-17
14 2016-10-10 2016-10-18  20 2016-10-18
```

Comment: df2.groupby('ID').resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index() returns no value unfortunately

Comment: Yes, maybe need pandas version `0.18.1` or newer. - [see](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations)

Answer (score 3):

With newer versions of Pandas (> 1.1), you can use the `explode` function to generate the dates:

```py
df['Entry Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Entry Date'])
df['Exit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Exit Date'])

(df.assign(Date = [pd.date_range(start, end) 
                   for start, end 
                   in zip(df['Entry Date'], df['Exit Date'])]
          )
   .explode('Date', ignore_index = True)
)
    ID Entry Date  Exit Date       Date
0   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-10
1   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-11
2   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-12
3   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-13
4   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-14
5   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-15
6   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-10
7   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-11
8   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-12
9   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-13
10  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-14
11  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-15
12  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-16
13  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-17
14  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-18
```

A much faster option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df['Entry Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'])
df['Exit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Exit Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
dates = pd.date_range(df['Entry Date'].min(), df['Exit Date'].max())
dates = pd.Series(dates,name='Date')

(df
.conditional_join(
    dates, 
    ('Entry Date', 'Date', '<='), 
    ('Exit Date', 'Date', '>='))
)
    ID Entry Date  Exit Date       Date
0   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-10
1   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-11
2   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-12
3   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-13
4   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-14
5   10 2016-10-10 2016-10-15 2016-10-15
6   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-10
7   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-11
8   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-12
9   20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-13
10  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-14
11  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-15
12  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-16
13  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-17
14  20 2016-10-10 2016-10-18 2016-10-18
```