# How to do outer merge of two dataframes for which column values are within a certain range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is followup question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range)

I have two `dataframes`:

```
print df_1

  timestamp      A          B
0 2016-05-15     0.020228   0.026572
1 2016-05-15     0.057780   0.175499
2 2016-05-15     0.098808   0.620986
3 2016-05-17     0.158789   1.014819
4 2016-05-17     0.038129   2.384590
5 2018-05-17     0.011111   9.999999


print df_2

  start                end  event    
0 2016-05-14   2016-05-16   E1
1 2016-05-14   2016-05-16   E2
2 2016-05-17   2016-05-18   E3
```

I would like to merge `df_1` and `df_2` and get the `event column` in `df_1` if the `timestamp` falls in between of `start` and `end`.

The problems, and the **differences** with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range) question, are

1) that `event`s `E1` and `E2` have the same `start` and `end`.

2) Also in `df_1` the **6th** row does not fall inside any of the intervals.

In the end I would like to have both of the events and for the row that does not have any event have `NA`.

So I would like my resulting `dataframe` to be like this

```
  timestamp      A          B         event
0 2016-05-15     0.020228   0.026572  E1
1 2016-05-15     0.057780   0.175499  E1
2 2016-05-15     0.098808   0.620986  E1
3 2016-05-15     0.020228   0.026572  E2 
4 2016-05-15     0.057780   0.175499  E2
5 2016-05-15     0.098808   0.620986  E2
6 2016-05-17     0.158789   1.014819  E3
7 2016-05-17     0.038129   2.384590  E3
8 2018-05-17     0.011111   9.999999  NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2016-05-15','2016-05-15','2016-05-15','2016-05-17','2016-05-17','2018-05-17'],
                     'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'start':['2016-05-14','2016-05-14','2016-05-17'],
                     'end':['2016-05-16','2016-05-16','2016-05-18'],
                     'event':['E1','E2','E3']})
df_1.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df_1.timestamp, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_2.start = pd.to_datetime(df_2.start, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_2.end = pd.to_datetime(df_2.end, format='%Y-%m-%d')

# convert game_ref_dt to long format with all the dates in between, and do a left merge on date
df_2_2 = pd.melt(df_2, id_vars='event', value_name='timestamp')
df_2_2.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df_2_2.timestamp)
df_2_2.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
df_2_2.drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)

df_2_3 = df_2_2.groupby('event').resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()

df_2 = pd.merge(df_2, df_2_3)
df_2 = df_2.drop(columns=['start', 'end'])

df_1 = df_1.merge(df_2,on='timestamp',  how='left')

print(df_1)
   timestamp  A event
0 2016-05-15  1    E1
1 2016-05-15  1    E2
2 2016-05-15  1    E1
3 2016-05-15  1    E2
4 2016-05-15  1    E1
5 2016-05-15  1    E2
6 2016-05-17  1    E3
7 2016-05-17  1    E3
8 2018-05-17  1   NaN
```

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997063/how-can-i-add-rows-for-all-dates-between-two-columns)

Also this solution, but **does not** give the `NA` at the last row

```
  import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2016-05-15','2016-05-15','2016-05-15','2016-05-17','2016-05-17','2018-05-17'],
                     'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'start':['2016-05-14','2016-05-14','2016-05-17'],
                     'end':['2016-05-16','2016-05-16','2016-05-18'],
                     'event':['E1','E2','E3']})   

df_try2 = pd.merge(df_1.assign(key=1), df_2.assign(key=1), on='key').query('timestamp >= start and timestamp <= end')    

print(df_try2)

   timestamp  A  key      start        end event
0  2016-05-15  1    1 2016-05-14 2016-05-16    E1
1  2016-05-15  1    1 2016-05-14 2016-05-16    E2
3  2016-05-15  1    1 2016-05-14 2016-05-16    E1
4  2016-05-15  1    1 2016-05-14 2016-05-16    E2
6  2016-05-15  1    1 2016-05-14 2016-05-16    E1
7  2016-05-15  1    1 2016-05-14 2016-05-16    E2
11 2016-05-17  1    1 2016-05-17 2016-05-18    E3
14 2016-05-17  1    1 2016-05-17 2016-05-18    E3
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which handles inequality joins efficiently:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df_1.conditional_join(
         df_2, 
         ('timestamp', 'start', '>='), 
         ('timestamp', 'end', '<='), 
         how = 'left')
     .loc[:, ['timestamp', 'A', 'B', 'event']]
)
   timestamp         A         B event
0 2016-05-15  0.020228  0.026572    E1
1 2016-05-15  0.020228  0.026572    E2
2 2016-05-15  0.057780  0.175499    E1
3 2016-05-15  0.057780  0.175499    E2
4 2016-05-15  0.098808  0.620986    E1
5 2016-05-15  0.098808  0.620986    E2
6 2016-05-17  0.158789  1.014819    E3
7 2016-05-17  0.038129  2.384590    E3
8 2018-05-17  0.011111  9.999999   NaN
```